# SQL- Math with Dates

Tags: sql, string, oracle, numbers

I am working out of Oracle SQL. I have some dates that may have been poorly formatted when loading.

I'm doing a basic `Max(date)-Min(Date)` to get the difference in days. My results are:

```
+000000156 00:00:00.000000
+000000149 00:00:00.000000
+00 00:00:00.000000
```

I want to do some basic math with these date differences (average, etc) but I get an error message.

How do I convert these strings into numbers?

Comment: Results of what?  What do the values look like in the table?  How does your expression return three rows?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the columns are timestamps, not dates, as the results are intervals not numbers. As you've found, Oracle have not got around to overloading the standard aggregate functions for intervals [(vote for this feature on the Oracle Database Ideas forum)](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2903) and currently you still have to either [write your own](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/avg-and-sum-for-intervals.html) or cast the timestamps to dates.

```
with demo (start_date, end_date) as
     ( select timestamp '2019-12-31 00:00:00', timestamp '2020-06-04 00:00:00' from dual union all
       select timestamp '2020-01-31 00:00:00', timestamp '2020-06-28 00:00:00' from dual
     )
select end_date - start_date as elapsed_interval
     , cast(end_date as date) - cast(start_date as date) as elapsed_days
from   demo;
```

```
ELAPSED_INTERVAL              ELAPSED_DAYS
----------------------------- ------------
+000000156 00:00:00.000000000          156
+000000149 00:00:00.000000000          149
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic math with dates:

date + number = date + number of days (also fractions)

```
SELECT SYSDATE + 1 FROM DUAL; -- tomorrow
```

date - number = date - number of days

```
SELECT SYSDATE - 1/24 FROM DUAL; -- one hour ago
```

date - date = numbers of days between dates (also fraction of days)

date + date = impossible

months_between(date1, date2) = returns months between two dates

add_months(date, number) = adds number (months) to date

if you have a string or number and it can be the n-th day of the year (for instance 156),
you can transform in date with TO_DATE('156', 'DDD')

if you have a string with a particular format, you can transform it in date with
TO_DATE(string, format of the date you imagine)

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

if you need the opposite transform, that is transforming date to char (or number), use TO_CHAR(date, format of the date)